# how to see which videos are uploaded to OneDrive and which are not?

Tags: 8.0, onedrive

Recently I run out of space on OneDrive and so my phone stopped uploading movies and pics.
when I freed some space the phone did not upload the old pics missing.
Now I can't find a way to see which pics and movies have been uploaded without visually checking them one by one. I'm on windows 8 on mobile. Anyone know how to see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**, it's not possible to see which images have been uploaded to OneDrive and which haven't on Windows Phone.

There is no sync feature or way to 'catch up' if some images haven't been uploaded due to errors, lack of space on OneDrive , etc. The same is also true if you turn off the auto-upload feature, then turn it back on at later date - it will not upload the older or missing photos.

You'll have to figure out which images are missing from your *OneDrive camera roll* and upload them yourself.

To aid with this, you can [use one of the official apps to sync your photos and videos](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/get-the-sync-apps) to your PC or Mac, then compare the two folders of files, and upload the missing ones.